# Can't access wp_filesystem in cron function

Tags: wp-cron, cron, wp-filesystem

I'm writing a plugin for integrating WP with Visma. It will basically spit out an XML file every third hour using wp cron (going to setup server cron for `wp-cron.php` on the live site) and save it to the uploads folder.

I got everything working when doing this manually (submit in wp-admin). However when running the cron function it seems `$wp_filesystem` isn't accessible nor is it possible to set it up with `request_filesystem_credentials()`. If I try to run `request_filesystem_credentials()` in the  cron function I get an error saying the function does not exist. If I leave it to my other function (hooked into `admin_init`) `$wp_filesystem` is just empty (non existent).

I'm trying to save stuff to uploads-folder in a cron function.

I've tried setting the FTP constants in `wp-config.php`. I've tried setting the priority of the `wp_filesystem` setup function to 1 (to make sure it runs as soon as possible).

I'd prefer using the `wp_filesystem` since it has so many benefits in terms of stability and security.

Comment: So of course as soon as I post this I find the solution. After looking for it for a day. I had to include the file handling the `request_filesystem_credentials` manually in the function. For reference this was `require ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So of course as soon as I post this I find the solution. After looking for it for a day. I had to include the file handling the request_filesystem_credentials manually in the function. For reference this was 
`require ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php';`